# Is there a way to tell which chests are mimics?

Tags: dark-souls

I've seen videos of players getting eaten alive by mimics and I'm trying to avoid that as much as possible, since I die enough as it is. Is there a way to differentiate which chests are mimics *before* I risk my life trying to open it?

I know I can attack the chests, but I've heard that this could potentially break the chest and destroy whatever item is inside.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there are a few ways to distinguish mimics from real chests:

1. The first clue in Dark Souls 1 is the chain. It is round and points towards the back of the chest for normal chests, but straighter and points forward for mimic chests. [image]
2. If you look closely and carefully, you will see mimic chests breathe and his teeth will be visible within a small gap. [video](https://youtu.be/U9oay_g0Ce8?t=23)
3. If you throw a [Lloyd's Talisman](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/lloyd-s-talisman) at a mimic chest, he will open himself, while still sleeping, allowing you to take the treasure without killing the mimic first. [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhwws3Z85zc)
4. And yes, you can attack it. Firstly, it attacking chests doesn't destroy them in Dark Souls 1 (only in Dark Souls 2, I believe). Secondly, you can always switch out your weapon and attack with your hand, which would never cause enough damage to destroy it.

Comment: Just to clarify about chests in DS2 - there are metal and wooden chests in game, and only wooden are destructible.

Answer (score -2):

Attack the chests will not break it in DS1, you can steer your camera near the chest and wait for a few second, if it breathe -> It's a mimic.